# TypeScript Knockout definition breaking change for observable arrays?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I had this code and it worked with TS 1.something:

```
private readonly pages: KnockoutObservableArray<number>;

constructor() {
    this.pages = ko.observableArray<number>();
}
```

But since upgrading to TS 4.something now I get the following on the one line in the constructor:

> Error TS2739  (TS) Type 'ObservableArray' is missing the following properties from type 'KnockoutObservableArray': mappedCreate, mappedRemove, mappedRemoveAll, mappedDestroy, mappedDestroyAll

As far as I can see, the typings and actual knockout versions are both 3.* so there shouldn't be incompatible changes there?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think this issue was down to me still having `@types/knockout.mapping` installed as well as upgrading `knockout.mapping`, which had it's own types in the package, and conflicts, and the house of cards fell down. Again.

So the answer is to remember to check whether you can uninstall any existing explicit TypeScript typings (either nuget or npm) when you upgrade to a newer version of a package.